# Simple Email Fowarding

Tags: smtp, mail-forwarding

Is there a program that handle smtp that has one and only one function: foward email from one email address to another email address? I know that this can be done using virtusertable with sendmail. What I am really looking for is a virtusertable without sendmail because the only thing this server does is forward mail.

I have a strong feeling that someone will ask "WHY!?!?!?" so I will answer that... I work for an organization in which every employee is actually employed by another company (please read "another company" to mean "every employee is employed by a company that the other employees are not employed by - for X employees, there are X companies sending one employee to the organization). The organization has a domain name. We want to have email addresses attached to the organization domain name, but we don't want to check yet another email account. So, we want all emails sent to the organization's domain name to be fowarded seamlessly to each employee's real email account.

Answer (score 2):

Good heavens - make this easy on yourself. Don't set up a second server that's only going to forward mail. That's silly. Use your existing mailserver.

Just set up the MX record for the second domain to point to your main domain, make your mailserver know that it's authoritative for the second domain, and set everyone up to have additional SMTP addresses using the second domain.

Easy and scalable - you don't have to do anything after setting this up.

The details of doing this will depend on your email server. Since you haven't told us what that is, I can't provide any more specifics for this one.

Comment: It appears to me that you are missing the point. Organization Z has employees from companies A, B, C, D, and E. Z is not a company with employees - it is a conglomeration of employees from other companies. So, if I forward Z's MX record to, say, company A, then how do I get emails sent to employees for B, C, D, and E delivered without trying to get company A to do work that they will refuse to do?

Comment: You don't forward the MX, you set up a basic [email alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_alias).

Comment: @yoonix - Yes. I agree. Is there a program that ONLY does email aliasing. I know I can use alias if I set up a local username for every alias. I know I can use .forward the same way. I know I can use virtusertable with sendmail. All of that is a lot of overhead that assumes fowarding is a side-function to sending and storing email. This will not send or receive email. It will only redirect/forward email.

Comment: Redirecting and forwarding *is* sending and receiving email.  It's simply not local delivery.  There are plenty of other SMTP servers if you don't like the complexity of sendmail's configuration files.  You need *something* to speak SMTP.  Look into postfix or Exim if you want something  a little slimmer.

Comment: I could tell you how to do this in Exchange in 5 minutes. I've recently done an Exchange migration for a company with over 50 domains, all supported in the same mail infrastructure. I'm not familiar enough with Unix mailservers to tell you what settings to make server-side.